# How to check if area of interest has clouds in a sentinel scene

Tags: python, satellite

I am using python script to download sentinel 2 imagery. given area of interest and cloud condition, it's easy to download the scene. but I am more interested to know if there is some way to check whether clouds are present or not in the area of interest. E.g. even with scene with 90% cloud coverage, there might be a case where the clouds may not be present in the AOI making the scene usable.

Comment: You could download the cloud mask polygons and intersect with your AOI.If you're downloading from AWS, it's MSK_CLOUDS_B00.gml in the [qi folder](http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/qi/)